# How to change value in other function?

Tags: javascript, onesignal, phonegap

I build an app on PhoneGap and I use OneSignal for PUSH notification. I tried to change value "rr" in my func.
Here is my code

```
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var rr = 0;
     function didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack(jsonData) {   
     rr=1;  
     var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(jsonData.payload.additionalData.ssylka, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,disallowoverscroll=yes');
     }

     function didOpenRemoteNotificationCallBack(jsonData) {
     alert('CLOSE APP');
     rr=1;  
     var newdata = JSON.parse ( jsonData.notification.payload.additionalData );
      var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(newdata.ssylka , '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,disallowoverscroll=yes');
     }


     window.plugins.OneSignal
      .startInit("***********************************")
      .handleNotificationReceived(didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack)
      .handleNotificationOpened(didOpenRemoteNotificationCallBack)
          .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
      .iOSSettings(iosSettings)
      .endInit();


     window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
      ipush = ids.userId;
      if(rr=='1'){}else{
      var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://top-star.kz/fr7/index.php?ipush='+ipush, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,disallowoverscroll=yes');
      }
    });
  }
 };
```

First. When I start an App i create a "rr" = 0. And I call "window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds" function. When I send PUSH in open App I call "didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack" fucntion and it's work great. But if I want to sent PUSH in close APP I call "didOpenRemoteNotificationCallBack" I can see alert('CLOSE APP') but InAppBrowser is not open with "jsonData.notification.payload.additionalData.ssylka" and don't changing "rr". It's stil "rr"=0; How to change "rr" to 1 in "didOpenRemoteNotificationCallBack" fucntion?

Comment: Try defining rr in the global scope (outside of receivedEvent)

Comment: brennanenanen, it's not work